# How to push back a vector onto a vector of vectors using an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have this code that creates an error:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void read_string(std::string &str,
         std::vector<std::string> &dir,
         std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &table,
         std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &result)
{

  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::iterator  it0;
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator it1;
  
  /*intent, iterate over each  element (vector of strings) of the
    vector of elements */
  for(it0 = table.begin(); it0 != table.end(); it0++){
    
    /*code to select specific vector of strings -added back to show intent*/
    if((*it0)[0]==str){

        /*selected vector of strings(element) are added to new table
        called "result" */
        for(it1 = (*it0).begin(); it1 != (*it0).end(); it1++){
        result.push_back(*it1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
test.cc:18:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::push_back(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
       result.push_back(*it1);
```

The intent of this code is to copy `table` onto `result`. What is the proper solution for this? In other words, how would you copy a vector of vectors onto another vector of vectors?

Comment: Too many layers? Peal them off one at a time.

Comment: "how would you copy a vector of vectors onto another vector of vectors?" - just `result=table`.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned, the intent is really not to copy vectors one for one onto the new table.... instead between the two for loops there is white space which would be populated with filtering code; I removed this to reduce the clutter.....so in essence it would be some vectors from the old table (table) to the new table (result)

Comment: `it1` is the pointer to the string of the inner vector, means with `push_back(*it1)` you are trying to push a `std::string` into a vector expecting a **vector of strings**. Wild guess, but if you want to filter the entire row/column (depending on what the inner vector is) you probably want to push_back(*it0)?

Comment: Respond to a comment by improving the question, rather than responding in a comment.

Comment: Hmm, my intent was to set it1 to point to the elements of the vector of vector objects pointed to by it0.

Comment: "some vectors from the old table (table) to the new table (result)" - consider `std::copy_if()` algorithm.

Comment: Hi user1810087 and Eugene, thanks for the pointers.. I have added the copy conditions to my example.... Any thoughts ?? For std::copy_if() what should be the predicate variable??

Comment: If you want to copy entire vectors from `table` to `result` you don't need the inner `it1` loop at all.  Just `result.push_back(*it0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, yes too many layers (I should have understood the first comment) - This is the desired code -

```
void read_string(std::string &str,
         std::vector<std::string> &dir,
         std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &table,
         std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &result)
{

  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::iterator  it0;
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator it1;
  

  //std::copy_if(table, table.size(), [](std::string p_str) {return
    
  for(it0 = table.begin(); it0 != table.end(); it0++){

    if((*it0)[0]==str){
    
      result.push_back(*it0);
      
    }
  }
  
  
  
}
```